# Lost camera on a Trenitalia train

Tags: italy, rome, venice, florence, trenitalia

I left my camera on the Trenitalia train from Rome to Venice on 09/11/15.

Departure time from Rome 12:50 arrival in Florence 14:22.

```
Roma Termini - Firenze S. M. Novella
> TICKET: Super Economy Fare - Second Class
> DEPARTURE: 9 November 2015 12:50
> ARRIVAL: 9 November 2015 14:22
> SEAT(S): Coach 6 - Seat 04D, Coach 6 - Seat 03D
```

In Florence they told me I need to contact the lost & found property in Venice after a couple of days when they will collect all found items. I'm coming back home tomorrow so I'll need to sort it out from London. Is there any way to speed the process up?

Comment: Probably you'll never see again your camera...

Comment: Phone and mail them every day for some days (some addresses are here http://www.trenitalia.com/tcom/Treni-Regionali/Veneto/oggetti-smarriti-veneto lost&found info page - mail addresses not related, but who cares).
There's **no** way to "speed up processes" with Trenitalia. Fingers crossed for you, but I agree with @Mattia

Answer (score 10):

I would like to put forth my experience. We forgot to take our camera when alighting at Florence; the train was bound to Naples. We had very little time left before boarding the next train to Pisa and from Pisa, the flight back to London.

We ran to the Trenitalia counter at Florence, and clearly told them the details of the location and attributes of the camera bag. The in-charge registered the complaint, and made a note of our address. Initially he was a bit hesitant to send the camera all the way to London, but somewhat agreed once we promised to pay the mail charges. He did not give us any phone number or email, but promised to contact us through email if the camera was available.

That said and done, we were not quite hopeful (especially after seeing Mattia's comment, and the numerous negative stories on the Internet on lost items in Italy). However to our pleasant surprise, the in-charge officer mailed us four days later acknowledging the presence of the camera in his office. He had somehow managed to retrieve it from the train and got it transferred back to Florence. In a few days, he mailed us our camera back after getting our credit card details in order to cover up for the postage.

I guess three things helped: one, we were travelling during the off-season, two, we knew precisely where our camera bag lay, and three, the officer-in-charge was helpful, diligent and sincere. There was literally nothing binding on him to go through all this trouble.

**TL,DR**: Do not lose all hope. Do not forget to register the complaint in person at the station (complaints via phone do not get registered).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. How do you know that complaints via phone do not get registered?

Comment: @JoErNanO: I called them after reaching London and told them about my loss. The lady on the phone said she could do nothing unless I had registered a complaint in the station. When I told her I did, she said I simply needed to wait for an email, and there is no "way to speed the process up", as the OP puts it.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that they told you to contact the lost & found office **of the city of Venice**, not of the train station. Such an office is run by the Comune, the city administration. You will find Venice's office here:

http://www.comune.venezia.it/flex/cm/pages/ServeBLOB.php/L/IT/IDPagina/80397

They run a monthly list of found property. You should try to review that. After some time, unclaimed objects are sold.